# Why is $f(s)=\int^{b}_{a}\frac{1}{t^s} dt$ holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> In complex analysis, let $a, b>0$ in $\mathbb R$,  $f(s)=\int^{b}_{a}1/t^s dt$, then $f$ is holomorphic for $Re(s)>0$.

If $s\neq 1$, then $f(s)=\frac{a^{1-s}}{(1-s)}-\frac{b^{1-s}}{(1-s)}$, but if $s=1$, then $f(s)=\ln\big(\frac{b}{a}\big)$, they seems quite different in the form, how to prove that it is holomorphic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problems like this, you can use [Morera's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) (and [Fubini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)).

For your particular case, check that the discontinuity of $\frac{a^{1-s}}{(1-s)}-\frac{b^{1-s}}{(1-s)}$ at $s=1$ is [removable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) and $\lim_{s\to 1}\cdots=\ln(b/a)$.

Comment: Morera's theorem is applicable here perfectly for $1/t^s$ is holomorphic in $s$.

Comment: @CYC, yes, is applicable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $0<a<b$ and write
$$f(s):=\int_a^b {1\over {\mathstrut t}^s}\>dt=\int_a^b e^{-s\,\log t}\>dt=\int_{\log a}^{\log b} e^{(1-s)u}\>du\ .$$
Now its obvious that $f$ is an entire function: We can differentiate under the integral sign.

Comment: How is that obvious? The same problem as the original seems happened again.